# Python write to file causing new line after second variable insertation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and the following is causing a new line at the second parameter:

```
file.write("'../../our-api-{0}-{1}.jar'".format(version, buildnum))
```

writes the following:

```
'../../our-api-2-1020
.jar'
```

If I take off the second parameter it writes correctly e.g.:

```
'../../our-api-2.jar'
```

How do I get the double variable to write correctly on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a trailing `\n` at the end of your variables.
There are two easy ways to debug this, simply do:

```
print( rep(buildnum) )
# or
print( [buildnum] )
```

And to solve it, you can do:

```
.format(version, buildnum.strip())
```

Comment: A better way to test for `\n` and other escaped characters is use `print(rep(buildnum))`. That's generally a good way to inspect data.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thanks for pointing that out, old habits die hard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the end purpose of your code snippet. However could you please try with below syntax :-

```
file.write("../../our-api-{0}-{1}.jar" + "format(version, buildnum)")
```

**or**

```
file.write("../../our-api-{0}-{1}.jar.format(version, buildnum)")
```